# Proving that one function is big o of another?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, asymptotics

I'm working through a big-O problem and have the intuition to know the answer, but don't feel comfortable in my proof. I need to prove from definitions (i.e. proving that there exists two constants $c$ and $n_0$) that

$$3^{3\log(n) + \log \log(n)}\log(n^{450}) \in O(9^{2\log(n)}).$$

Now I end up selecting an $n_0$ value of 1, and a $c$ value of 1. The entire left side of my equation collapses into $0$. I'm left with $0 \leq 9^0 = 1$, which is true.

Now my questions: this seems far too easy. Am I really allowed to pick those constants myself? Also, the example I used just doesn't seem very rigorous, but it does make it clear how one side grows much faster than the other, does it not? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have checked the inequality only for $n_0$ you need to check it also for all $n>n_0$.

Comment: Ahhh, there's the rub. In that case I'd like to discuss my second approach, which might make more headway. I would change the right side to $3^{4\log(n)}$. It's clear that the first term on the left must be less than this...but now how can I prove that the $\log(n^{450})$ term becomes insignificant at large $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have checked the inequality only for $n_0$ you need to check it also for all $n>n_0$.

An strategy, among many, could be to divide both functions.

$$\begin{align}\frac{3^{3\log(n)+\log\log(n)}\log(n^{450})}{9^{
2log(n)}}&=\frac{3^{3\log(n)+\log\log(n)}\log(n^{450})}{3^{4
log(n)}}\\&=450\cdot3^{-\log(n)+\log\log(n)}\log(n)\\&=450\cdot3^{-\log(n)+\log\log(n)}3^{\frac{\log\log(n)}{\log(3)}}\\&=450\cdot3^{-\log(n)+\log\log(n)+\frac{\log\log(n)}{\log(3)}}\end{align}$$

And try to prove this is bounded for large $n$. So far this is the definition. What we can try to do now is to compute the limit as $n\to\infty$. If this limit is exists, as a finite limit, then it follows that the quotient is bounded.

In our particular case we can compute 
$$\begin{align}\log\log(n)-\log(n)+\frac{\log\log(n)}{\log(3)}&=\log\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)+\log(\log(n)^{1/\log(3)})\\&=\log\left(\frac{(\log(n))^{1+1/\log(3)}}{n}\right)\end{align}$$

Apply L'Hospital to the fraction inside the first $\log$. We get

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{\log(3)}\right)\frac{(\log(n))^{1/\log(3)}}{n}$$

and again

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{\log(3)}\right)\frac{1}{\log(3)}\frac{1}{(\log(n))^{1-1/\log(3)}n}\to0$$

Therefore the original fraction tends to $450\cdot3^0=450$ and is therefore bounded. From this limit we know that any constant greater than $450$ should work for some large $n_0$.

Comment: How can I rigorously explain the dropping of the $\log(n^{450})$ term as insignificant?

Comment: @user212787 The explanation is that I ate it. Don't drop it. Let me add it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write all of this out for me! This is really helpful. But I just don't understand given the last part how I can find exactly what $n_0$ value makes this all work.

Comment: @user212787 That is a different story. Notice that that means solving an inequality. If solving equations is hard in general, solving inequalitites is, at most, as difficult. The thing is that in this context you often only need to show $n_0$ and $C$ exist, without actually computing them.

Comment: I see! So this proof essentially shows that regardless of the value chosen for $n_0$, a value greater than 450 for $c$ will always work for all $n$?

Comment: @user212787 No, this proof doesn't say that. It only shows given a $C>450$ there is some $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$ $|f(x)|<C|g(n)|$, where $f$ and $g$ are the two functions in your problem. But we don't know which $n_0$.